# Move Sharepoint Wiki between site collections

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, wiki

I've got two sharepoint site collections. Now i have a Wiki in one and i want to move it to te second one. I did the move with creating a template and import it into the new one. The problem í've got now is the links. The Wiki links are refering to the old location.

Does any one a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the SharePoint Wiki system is that it resolves the Wiki style links [[link]] at save time to absolute links to the page in the Wiki page list.
I think you will need to write some code that loops through and updates the text in your Wiki pages. Use the WSS object model to to find and update each list item that represents a Wiki page.

You can also have a look at [www.sharepointproducts.com](http://www.sharepointproducts.com) where you can download a free version of a tool (CopyMove for SharePoint) that can also move Wiki pages across site collections. It does, however, not update the links on the Wiki pages. But it is my tool - so I will give it some thought whether to add support for this. It is not the first time I have heard about this problem.